# How to remove specific <script> on click

Tags: javascript

I have a number of  tags on my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toRemove.js"></script>
```

I've tried:

```
html.replace(/<script type="text/javascript" src="toRemove.js">.*<\/script>/ims, " ");
```

Comment: Scripts can't be removed from the page. You can remove a script element, but the program remains.

Comment: What is your purpose of deleting the script tag?

Comment: You need to escape the slash: `/<script type="text\/javascript.../`

Comment: @A1rPun - this script is very heavy on page load, so when i open a new window (which is a copy of the current) it carrys out extra processes and there is no need for this tag.

Comment: If each script contributes to a namespace, you can set that namespace object to `null` I suppose.

Comment: @OamPsy Consider doing it the other way.. load the script only when you need it.

Comment: @OamPsy: If it's heavy on page load, load it at the end of the page, which is considered a good practice.

Comment: Adding a script works : it will be ran after being append.
Removing works as well but it's useless : it has allready been ran the vars and objects are stored in memory etc.

Comment: You could load your page without the scripts , and then add only the necessary scripts one by one with something like (function() { var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.src = 'foo.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, s); })();

Answer (score 1):

As other people already stated, you cannot "*unload*" a script by removing its node. However, technically you can of course remove the script node. I would not recommend using a RegEx on the documents HTML string, but rather

```
[].forEach.call(document.head.getElementsByTagName('script'), function( scr ) {
  if( scr.getAttribute( 'src' ) === 'toRemove.js' ) {
      scr.parentNode.removeChild( scr );
  }
});
```

Ideally, you're not working in your life document there, but rather create a clone via `createDocumentFragment` for instance, which you can then re-use for whatever reason.

Comment: Why not to use [`scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.scripts) collection, OP didn't say if these scripts are within `head` or `body`.

Comment: Why not `document.querySelectorAll('script[src=toRemove.js]')`? Should work even for IE8.

Comment: Y U NO ! Well, this is just an example, of course you can use other query methods.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - IE8 support is a must :(

Comment: @OamPsy Well, `querySelectorAll` is not your problem :). `Array.prototype.forEach` is. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try querySelectorAll which will fetch script tag from body as well as head.

```
var scriptTagElements=document.querySelectorAll('script[src=toRemove.js]')

for(var i=0;i<scriptTagElements;i++){

    scriptTagElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(scriptTagElements[i]);

}
```